# Arduino serial.available() trigger keypress

Tags: arduino

I use Arduino Serial Monitor to enter WiFi login and password. The next time I run a program I don't need to enter the same data. I can press "enter" key twicely because Serial Monitor remember these inputs (I think so).
I would like to program wait ten seconds and trigger pressing ENTER key if no data is entered by user. How to do it? I did not find examples with similar implementation.

```
while (Serial.available() == 0) {
  }
  Serial.readBytesUntil(10, password, 50);
  Serial.println(password);
```

When I press enter key without entering any data there is no data output on Serial Monitor but WiFi connection is successful.

Answer (score 0):

I managed with Serial.setTimeout after Serial.begin and commenting these lines:

```
while (Serial.available() == 0) {     
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You use esp8266 module I expect. esp8266 remembers the last STA connection ssid and password and connects automatically at default.

Usual is to do

```
if (Serial.available()) {
  Serial.readBytesUntil('\r', password, 50);
  Serial.println(password);
}
```

to not block the loop